# When I use the extension operator, the ts type of rest is A or B. How to handle this situation

Tags: typescript

```js
function a(val: string) {
  console.log(val);
}

function b(val: boolean) {
  console.log(val);
}

function func(fn: typeof a | typeof b) {
  return (...rest: Parameters<typeof fn>) => {
    fn(...rest);
  };
}
```

vscode warning The extension parameter must have a tuple type or be passed to the rest parameter. ts(2556)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m not sure what you need to achieve with the function func.
If you want to create a generic caller, for many function like a and b, you miss to pass parameters. Actually at line 111, you pass a type (which is the union of all parameters of all possible type of fn. You need to pass to fn good parameters, of *that* type.

you can do something like that

```
const genericCaller = <P, F extends (val: P) => void>(fn: F, val: P): void => {
    fn(val);
};

genericCaller(a, 'hello me');
genericCaller(b, true);
```

But if you might have more complexe function to call like function c :

```
function c(val: boolean, val2: number) {
    console.log(val + ' ' + val2);
}

const moreGenericCaller = <F extends (...args: any) => void>(fn: F, param: Parameters<F>): void => {
    fn(param);
};

moreGenericCaller(a, ['hello me']);
moreGenericCaller(b, [true]);
moreGenericCaller(c, [true, 6]);
```

notice that in that cas you should pass parameters as a tuple using square brackets

Or with return type if needed

```
const moreGenericCallerWithReturn = <F extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: F, param: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> => {
    return fn(param);
};
```

Hope that would help